# What does np.sqrt (2.0 / 9/64) mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There was the following tensor flow code

```
conv_w = tf.get_variable ("conv_% 02d_w"% (i + 1), [9,9,64,64], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer (stddev=np.sqrt(2.0/9/64)))
```

I do not know what "(2.0 / 9/64)" in "np.sqrt" means here.

Why is the division operator (/) twice?

That code is probably a normal distribution.

I wonder what 2.0, 9, and 64 each do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know what "(2.0 / 9/64)" in "np.sqrt" means here.

Hello,

**2.0/9/64** basically produces the same result as **(2.0/9)/64**.
It's a division:

- First a division **2.0/9** is made
- Then the result is divided by **64**.

Result for both **2.0/9/64** or **(2.0/9)/64** is approximatively **0.003472222222222222**

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a number that represents the deviation in the normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

In Python a/b/c == (a/b)/c
So it is essentialy (2/9)/64.

2.0 is used to make sure that result is float (it should be float even if you use 2 instead of 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

This is just 2 divided by 9, then the result divided by 64, where both divisions are real divisions. This is equal to `(2.0/9.0)/64.0`. Presumably this expression has a theoretical justification, since 9 and 64 are dimensions of this tensor.